# Why can't my header file be located by the compiler?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, vmware-player

So I don't know anything about makefiles but I am trying to compile multiple cpp files and one header file that contains function prototypes for each of the cpp files. I am trying to compile by using the following command:

g++ main.cpp func1.cpp func2.cpp -o hello

And I am getting the following error:

main.cpp:4:24: fatal error: funcHeader.h: No such file or directory.

I have tried following the instructions in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw9wHbFTnAQ none of which seemed to work. Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I cannot believe what a silly mistake I made. Instead of writing

```
#include "funcHeader.h"
```

I wrote

```
#include <funcHeader.h>
```

Thanks though for all your help